# How to get https:// url from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I get the url of this link?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you point at there is known as the download URL of the file. To get that URL, you'll want to follow the instructions on [accessing a file through a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url):

```
StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child("path/to/photo2.jpg");

photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        System.out.println(uri.toString());
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        throw exception
    }
});
```